# Don't redeclare extended form type as service to pass parent arguments

Tags: dependency-injection, symfony, symfony-forms

I created a symfony form type in which I want to be able to use the entity manager.

So I declared it as a service as mentioned in the symfony documentation:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_dependencies.html#define-your-form-as-a-service

Now I want to create another form type extending  the first one.
But it seem I need to declare this new form type as a service too even if it is extending from the first one already declared as a service.

Is it possible to tell symfony to detect that the new form is extending the first form type and automatically inject dependencies of the parent class?

```php
// src/AppBundle/Form/TaskType.php

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class TaskType extends AbstractType
{
    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

```php
// src/AppBundle/Form/TaskObject1Type.php

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class TaskObject1Type extends TaskType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Short answer is no.  The form component uses the form type class name to pull the service from the container.  I suppose you could try to find that code and see if you could modify it but that would be a lot of work just to avoid adding a few lines of service definition.  There is a parent service capability that might help: http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/parent_services.html

Answer (score 0):

You should not extend form type in Symfony by extending classes.
Instead, use should use `getParent` method to point into parent type.

So, instead

```
class ChildType extends ParentType
{
    ...
}
```

use

```
class ChildType extends AbstractType
{
    ...
    public function getParent()
    {
        return ParentType::class;
    }
}
```

So you will need to deal with parent classes dependencies.

Comment: This is not working as expected because I need to call the parent build form (see my edited post). I tried to add both `extends ParentType` and method `getParent()` but I still have `Too few arguments` exception